# How to sort a dictionary to print from highest value to lowest for each key?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

txt would contain a something like this:

```
Matt Scored: 10
Jimmy Scored: 3
James Scored: 9
Jimmy Scored: 8
....
```

The code I managed to put together (quite new to python) is here:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
#opens the class file in order to create a dictionary
dictionary = {}
#splits the data so the name is the key while the score is the value
f = open('ClassA.txt', 'r')
d = {}
for line in f:
    firstpart, secondpart = line.strip().split(':')
    dictionary[firstpart.strip()] = secondpart.strip()
    columns = line.split(": ")
    letters = columns[0]
    numbers = columns[1].strip()
    if d.get(letters):
        d[letters].append(numbers)
    else:
        d[letters] = list(numbers)
#sorts the dictionary so it has a alphabetical order
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
print (sorted_dict)
```

And the problem I encountered is when trying to print the dictionary with the names and the scores from highest to lowest is that it will either only print the name with the highest score when using the `max` function or if im using the `itemgetter` it only seems to work for lowest to highes. So I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me out. Anything is appreciated, explain it if possible :)

Comment: don't edit away your question once answered! That's hardly going to help the next person along...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(
    sorted((key, list(sorted(vals, reverse=True))) 
           for key, vals in d.items()))
```

This snippet sorts the names in alphabetic order and the scores for each name from highest to lowest. The `reverse` parameter in sort methods can be used to force the order from highest to lowest.

For example:

```
>>> d = {"Matt": [2,1,3], "Rob": [4,5]}
>>> OrderedDict(sorted((key, list(sorted(vals, reverse=True))) for key, vals in d.items()))
OrderedDict([('Matt', [3, 2, 1]), ('Rob', [5, 4])])
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm could uou tell me what the "vals" stands for or does so i can just understand that bit better?

Comment: @PythonPerson `d.items()` is an iterable of tuples with two items: the first is the key, the second is the value. So `for key, vals in d.items()` splits those tuples: the key goes to `key` and the value goes to `vals`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
# regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

# dictionary sorted by value
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't entirely solve my problem,  it prints from lowest to highest which is the opposite from what i wish to do as well as it doesnt in alphabetical order along with the highest score next to it as the first key.

Comment: @PythonPerson -- just pass `reverse=True` to `sorted`.  Alternativly, since the values are numeric, you could use `key = lambda t: -t[1]` (e.g. negate the value), but I think the reverse=True is probably better.