# How to sort multiple digit dictionary values from highest to lowest

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Is there a way to sort dictionary values with multiple digits? I have tried the method used here: [How to sort a dictionary to print from highest value to lowest for each key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179125/how-to-sort-a-dictionary-to-print-from-highest-value-to-lowest-for-each-key) , but it only works for integer values which are single digits. For example, my code currently looks like this:

```
for line in students:
        student = line.split(' ')
        d[student[1]] = (student[3])
        print (d)
     od = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
     print(od)
```

where students is the result of .readlines() for this text file and I'm using the first score:

```
Name= kirsty Score= 9 10 10 `
Name= anne Score= 4 5 6  
Name= charlie Score= 1 1 1 
Name= bruce Score= 7 8 9 
Name= danny Score= 10 11 12
```

Danny should be the first entry in the dictionary, however my actual output is this:

```
[('kirsty', '9'), ('bruce', '7'), ('anne', '4'), ('danny', '10'), ('charlie', '1')]
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: try `lambda x: int(x[1])` as sorting key!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert to `int`s for comparison. The behavior your seeing is from comparing strings.

e.g-

```
sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse  = True)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed- sorry I answered so late!

Answer (score 1):

Change your key function to convert the value the ordering is computed over to be a number. Assuming you're only using integers, the sort line would be:

`od = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)`